# Get Particular string from NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I get `NSString` as `session["token2"] = "Token 90dcee1adc82c25f51fc9542e4f9efd338caa0b5"` and i just want `90dcee1adc82c25f51fc9542e4f9efd338caa0b5` so what is the best way to get that token?

Comment: Parse as json, using the option to allow fragments.  You'll get a dictionary with a key `token2`.

Comment: @Avi sure let me try once. :-)

Comment: @Avi i tried this way is this correct way?

NSData *jsonData = [stringWithToken dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                        NSError *e;
                        NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:nil error:&e];

Comment: You need to specify the option that allows fragments.

Comment: Well i passed `NSJSONReadingAllowFragments` in option and i got the same string. i mean it was not converted into the deictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are two methods of string, you can use that and get your final token.

```
NSString *strToken = @"Token 90dcee1adc82c25f51fc9542e4f9efd338caa0b5";
```

**1st method :**

```
NSString *strToken1 = [[strToken componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] lastObject];
```

**2nd method :**

```
NSString *strToken2 = [strToken substringFromIndex:6];
```

By both method you can get your token.

Comment: Hi @Dhanesh actually i was doing 2nd method but i felt like i should not use hard coded values, but let me try 1st method may be it will help.

Comment: yeah it worked, but was looking for something like converting the string into the json data but didnt work. But thanks to you.